# Change the nth character to a Random character in Linux

Tags: linux, random, awk, sed

i have a text file with a list of numbers. I would like to change the 11th character to a random number.
input.txt
00018674395618674395 
00018674396618674396 
00018674397618674397 
00018674398618674398 
00018674399618674399 
00018674400618674400

```
 sed 's/^\(.\{11\}\)./\1'$(((RANDOM % 10)+1))'/' input.txt > output.txt
```

However, this just generates a random number and inserts it as the 11th character, so the 11th number becomes for example 4 in every-line.
I would like a random number in each line
00018674395618674395 
00018674396318674396 
00018674397518674397 
00018674398718674398 
00018674399718674399 
00018674400218674400

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`srand()` seeds the random number generator in case you want a different string of random numbers each time you generate the results. If not, you can remove all of `BEGIN {srand()}`. (The `-*-` is not really in the output, it's just to make it easier to see where the random digit is placed.)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {srand()} {print substr($0,1,10) (int(10 * rand())) substr($0,12)}' r.txt
         -*-     
00018674398618674395
00018674394618674396
00018674395618674397
00018674391618674398
00018674394618674399
00018674405618674400
         -*-     

$ awk 'BEGIN {srand()} {print substr($0,1,10) (int(10 * rand())) substr($0,12)}' r.txt
         -*-     
00018674399618674395
00018674394618674396
00018674396618674397
00018674397618674398
00018674391618674399
00018674405618674400
         -*-
```

Comment: Thanks Jas,thats perfect.